# Reentrant Mutex in Rust standard library

Tags: rust

Why Rust doesn't have Reentrant Mutex in the standard library. As of now I'm relying on `parking_lot` crate for this type mutex.

Comment: This question does not look like a good fit for SO: only maintainers can reliably answer such, so it should be asked on dedicated forums or support channels instead. However, your district question already was, and probably several times. Check out this PR for a long discussion on this matter: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1632

Answer (score 1):

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/libs-team/issues/193) to add a reentrant mutex to the standard library, but without scanning Zulip threads its hard to determine if and/or when this would be available.

Rust does not have a "batteries included" standard library; it is pretty minimal compared to other languages. It is common to reach for third-party dependencies for many "common" things. Because there is a quality community implementation (from parking-lot), there is probably little urgency to have this in the standard library.